# can i continue in a forM_ with exception?

Tags: haskell, webdriver

i am using webdriver for some data crawling on one of my lists with the following code:

```
let links = ["xxx.com/index.html", "xxx.com/contact.html", "xxx.com/people.html"]
forM_ links $ \l -> do
  waitUntil 15 $ do
    a <- findElem (ByClass "has")
    liftIO $ print a
```

Now, the `xxx.com/contact.html` or any other element might not have an element with `has` class and trows the `NoSuchElement` exception that terminates the iteration.

How can i continue after exception and print the results for all the list?

Thanks!

Comment: you could [`catch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:catch) the exception

Comment: I'm not sure which language you using, but you could search for exception handling for that language and you will get your answer

Comment: @epsilonhalbe that `catch` will work only in `IO`. The given commands work in `WebDriver wd => k -> wd a`.